# how to implement javascript validation and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have code on which on submit button I have to check all validation and simultaneously run ajax. I have complex code but problem is shown in demo code.

When I am going to check validation and run ajax then value goes always true even if I write return false and submit action is perform.

This is happening because nature of ajax which run asynchronously. And some one has given me solution as link [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

But I need solution in code So please solve my this type of problem. I am facing this problem from more than one month. My code sample is below.

checkjavascript.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    die("lokesh");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            function checkjs(){                
                if(document.getElementById('a').value==""){
                    alert("insert a");
                    return false;
                }
                if(document.getElementById('b').value==""){
                    alert("insert b");
                    return false;
                }
                if(document.getElementById('c').value==""){
                    alert("insert c");
                    return false;
                }
                var companyname = document.getElementById('b').value;
                var username = document.getElementById('c').value;
                jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",           
            dataType: "json",   
            url:'checkexisting.php',
            data:{
                companyname: companyname,username: username,
            },
            success:function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                            return false;
                            //$( "#lokeshform" ).submit();
                            //jQuery( "#lokeshform" ).submit();
                            document.forms.form.submit();                            
            }
            });                
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post" name="form" id="lokeshform" onsubmit="return checkjs();">
            <input type="text" id="a">
            <input type="text" id="b">
            <input type="text" id="c">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

checkexisting.php

```
 <?php
$companyname = $_REQUEST['companyname'];
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$response = $companyname.$username;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to submit form when AJAX Request has some variable set as true or false?

Comment: if false then do not submit

Comment: i have condition from where it will decide true or false

Comment: so in you response, can't you just check, like if(response.validate == true) {//Submit the form}

Answer (score 0):

```
 success:function(response) {
     if (condition_to_form_submit) {
         document.forms.form.submit(); 
     }                           
  }
```

condition_to_form_submit depends on your specific needs (probably you need to check some response values)

EDIT: didn't see that @Parag Bhayani already recommended this kind of solution. Credit to him

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkValid(){
    return new Promise(resolve,reject){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",           
            dataType: "json",   
            url:'checkexisting.php',
            data:{
                companyname: companyname,username: username,
            },
            success:function(response) {
                 resolve(); //or reject(err) depend on response data                   
            }
        });                 
    }
}
function submitForm(){
    document.forms["form"].submit();
}
$('#submitBtn').on('click',function(e){
    checkValid().then(submitForm).catch(function(err){
        alert(err);
    })
}
```

move submit button outer of the form